# How to show all events as default in SharePoint Calendar list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

In the monthly view, it defaults to only show 3 events per day. How can I make it show all events as default without using any codes and without clicking the expand buttons?

Answer (score 1):

OOTB SharePoint doesn't give an option to show all the events in expanded view. You can try anyone of the below approach/ work around.

1. Code approach

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b52b0e04-3b4f-4a08-a5f4-43da5720322f/sharepoint-online-calendar-expand-by-default?forum=SP2016

2. Creating a page and adding calendar webpart

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2140768-sharepoint-online-calendar-expand-by-default

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint doesn’t provide the ability to change the maximum number of events shown per day in monthly view. So it would not be possible to change the default calendar list without using code.

The **code approach** from [Karthik Jaganathan](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/10555/karthik-jaganathan)’s reply works well.

Edit the Monthly page view and inset a **Script Editor** web part, then insert the script and save the page. The events will be displayed in expanded view automatically.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar;
var count=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    myVar = setInterval(expandFunc, 300);        
});

function expandFunc() { 
    $("a[evtid='expand_collapse']").each(function(i){
        if($(this).text().indexOf("more item")>-1){
            $(this).children().click();
            count=i+1;
            }                                             
    });
    if($("a[evtid='expand_collapse']").length==count){
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }                             
}
</script>
```

[image: Test Outcome]

Answer (score 0):

In reference to "The code approach from Karthik Jaganathan’s reply" -

From my testing, if there is no expand/collapse visible on the calendar (because no day has more than 3 events), the line clearInterval(myVar); never runs and the function continues to run indefinitely.

Change var count=1; to var count=0;

Also, this seems to only run for the first month.  When changing to other months, it doesn't get triggered.